# 'The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database. (rsCannotValidateEncryptedData)'

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

In MSCRM Server When I want to create a new OU in Deployment CRM , get below Error:
"Setup Failed to validate ..."
and when I opened report server url ,got this Error:
'The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database. (rsCannotValidateEncryptedData)'

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: The error messages explain the "what".  Can you provide any details that would help to explain the "why"?

Answer (score -1):

I change SQL Server Reporting Service User to network service and then my issue resolved

Comment: Are you the person who originally asked the question?

Comment: @music2myear  Yes, but I do not know why I am not owner of this question !!!!!!!!!

Comment: Because you created the account while not logged on, or while logged on anonymously. You can request your accounts be merged here: https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts